# Set UNIQUE priorities ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table

```
id   year   name   activation
1    2013   TEST   1

id A_I
year, name UNIQUE
name, activation UNIQUE
```

I use this query to INSERT/UPDATE data:

```
INSERT INTO LISTE_DATI
    (year, name, activation)
VALUES
    ('$varray[1]', '$varray[2]', '$varray[3]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    year= '$yr',
    name= '$na',
    activation= '$act'
```

If I send this data to the table:

```
$yr = 2014
$na = TEST
$act = 0
```

the query `INSERT` data in the table. This is ok for me!

If I send this data to the table:

```
$yr = 2015
$na = TEST
$act = 1
```

the query `UPDATES` the first row `(2013/TEST/1)` in the table. 
In this case I'd like to have an INSERT too.

How can I adjust it?

Comment: By creating an unique key on all three columns?

Comment: Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling your `INSERT` query, that when it finds a duplicate (`UNIQUE`) key, to instead update that row.

You are inserting `(2012, 'TEST', 1)`.  This is a duplicate key; the `name, activation` key, your 2nd `UNIQUE` key!  You already have a row with `'TEST', 1`; the row with `id=1`.

The `INSERT` query updates that row, since it's a duplicate key.

You need to modify the keys on your table so that it reflects the data you want in it.  What do you want the `INSERT` query to consider a duplicate?  Create your `UNIQUE` keys based on that.

Comment: Thank you! So, a solution could be to remove the second unique key (name, activation) and have only the first (year, name)?

Comment: @Perocat: That's one solution.  Depending on your data, you can also make a UNIQUE key on all 3 fields (year, name, activation).

Comment: Thank you.. no an unique key on all 3 fields won't work. I cannot have two activation for the same name, but 2 activation for the same year yes...

Comment: Something isn't working yet. Now I have only one `UNIQUE(year, name)`. If I run the query with `$yr = 2014, $na = TEST, $att = 0`, it `UPDATES` insted of `INSERT`. Why? 2014, TEST is not a duplicate key...

Comment: @Perocat: Are you sure there isn't a row with `(2013, 'TEST')`?

Comment: Yes there is a row `2013   TEST   0`. I am now inserting `2014 TEST 0`. `2014 TEST != 2013 TEST` so why UPDATE and not insert?

Comment: Ok, something was wrong with the table... maybe the index weren't dropped. Is it necessary to set a name for a new `UNIQUE`? I mean: `ALTER TABLE LISTE_DATI ADD UNIQUE(field, field, ...)` or `ALTER TABLE LISTE_DATI ADD UNIQUE `unique_name`(field, field, ...)` are both correct?

Comment: @Perocat: I don't know if keys *need* names, but I usually give them one.